# what is alternative of 'startIntentSenderForResult(android.content.IntentSender, int, android.content.Intent, int, int, int)' is deprecated

Tags: java, android

startIntentSenderForResult(android.content.IntentSender, int, android.content.Intent, int, int, int)' is deprecated
which I use alternative

Answer (score -1):

Following the documentation:

> This method has been deprecated in favor of using the Activity Result API which brings increased type safety via an [ActivityResultContract](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContract) and the prebuilt contracts for common intents available in [androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts), provides hooks for testing, and allow receiving results in separate, testable classes independent from your activity. Use [registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContract, ActivityResultCallback)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/ComponentActivity#registerForActivityResult(androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContract%3CI,O%3E,androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCallback%3CO%3E)) passing in a [StartIntentSenderForResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult) object for the [ActivityResultContract](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContract).

Comment: Would be nice if you could provide examples of using ActivityResultContract, and perhaps explain why it was deprecated in the first place.